# How to plot a distribution of planes

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How can one plot a distribution of planes in $\mathbb R^3$ in *Mathematica*?

For some point $p=(x,y,t)\in\mathbb R^3$, I want to attach a plane spanned by $X(p)=\left(1,0,\frac{y}{2}\right)$ and by $Y(p)=\left(0,1,-\frac{x}{2}\right)$, in order to obtain something like this:

[image: some planes]

(The above figure is taken from [here](http://lukyanenko.net/gallery.php?page=3).)

Comment: What about the code/source for the shown image?

Comment: The link is http://lukyanenko.net/gallery.php?page=3

Comment: Suggestion: you can put the link into the question, where it will be permanently preserved. Also, it usually helps to show what you tried already.

Comment: I'm going to add the link in the question. But I don't know how to plot something like this. I'm an occasional Mathematica user, so I'm not expert at all.

Comment: I've edited the post, I hope now it is clearer.

Comment: Make a `Table` of `Polygon`, using the equations of the planes to get the coordinates for the vertices.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
a = .2;
base = Polygon[{{-a, -a, 0}, {-a, a, 0}, {a, a, 0}, {a, -a, 0}}/2];
r = 2 a;

Graphics3D[{

  GeometricTransformation[
   base,
   Flatten[
    Table[
         TranslationTransform[{x, y, 0}] @* RotationTransform[
            {{0, 0, 1}, Cross[{1, 0, .5 y}, {0, 1, -.5 x}]}],
     {x, - r, r, a}, {y, - r, r, a}
     ], 1]
   ],
  {  Thick
     ,
     Blue, (* normal to base*)
     Arrow[{#, # + {0, 0, .2}} ]
     ,
     Green, (* spanning vectors *)
     Arrow[{#, # + .2 {1, 0, .5 #[[2]]}} ], 
     Arrow[{#, # + .2 {0, 1, -.5 #[[1]]}} ]
     ,
     Red, (* normal to spanned plane*)
     Arrow[{#, # + .2 Cross[{1, 0, .5 #[[2]]}, {0, 1, -.5 #[[1]]}]  }]
  } &@{r, r, 0}
 }, 
  PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

and with [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m)'s suggestion about `BoxRatios`:

```
Graphics3D[{
  base,
  GeometricTransformation[
   base,
   Flatten[
    Table[
     TranslationTransform[{x, y, 0}]@*RotationTransform[
       {{0, 0, 1}, Normalize@Cross[{1, 0, .5 y}, {0, 1, -.5 x}]}],
     {x, -r, r, a}, {y, -r, r, a}
     ], 1]
   ]

  }, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4`}]
```

[image]

```
a = .1;
r = 5 a;
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the original picture seems to be using the `BoxRatios` setting of `Plot3D[]`...

Comment: @J.M., you're right!

Comment: I know. ;) For completeness: `Lighting -> "Classic"`.

Comment: @J.M. I won't doubt again!

Comment: @Kuba: Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a very compact version, constructed through the magic of dot products:

```
With[{a = 1/5, r = 2/5}, 
     Graphics3D[Polygon[Flatten[Table[{x, y, 0} + # & /@
                                      (a {{1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}} .
                                      {{1, 0, y/2}, {0, 1, -x/2}}/2),
                                      {x, -r, r, a}, {y, -r, r, a}], 1]],
                Axes -> True, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.4}, 
                Lighting -> "Classic", PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: so, they're all just tilted like that?]