# Plotting several vector fields in 3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I wish to plot a distribution in R3 as in the picture below

[image]

I know that Wolfram allows to plot sveral vector fields as it is in the page

VectorPlot3D[{field1,field2,…},{x,xmin,xmax},{y,ymin,ymax},{z,zmin,zmax}]

> **Question:**  How do I fill out the part field1, field2? Do I have to define a function?
>
> **Remark:** In my specific problem, I have a field of hyperplanes $H$ on $\mathbb R^3$ generated by the vector fields

$$ H= \{\partial_x, \partial_y - x \partial_z\}$$

Comment: Like that: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102059/5478?

Comment: @Kuba Like that. I just couldn't follow the coding. I'm just a begginer yet, could you provide some details?

Comment: I'd say it is your turn. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Kuba I think I got it here! Thanks.